# How do we get value from inside the arrow function on outer scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which requests from api and gets data in response. How can I get assigned variables inside arrow function i.e. priceEvents, defaultDate etc after all the api request and set state after that? Is it a good approach on setting state after all the api requests?

```
axios.get(`/api/v1/test/prices?date_from=${ currentDate.format() }`, { headers: headers })
.then((response) => {
    const priceEvents = response.data;
    const defaultDate = this.cal.$calendar.fullCalendar("getDate");
    //this.setState({ priceEvents, defaultDate });
})
.then((response) => {
    return axios.get(`/api/v1/test/events?date_from=${ currentDate.format() }`, { headers: headers })
})
.then((response) => {
    const bookingEvents = response.data;
    //this.setState({ bookingEvents });

});

console.log(bookingEvents);
console.log(priceEvents);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the values along from one promise to another:

```js
axios.get(`/api/v1/test/prices?date_from=${ currentDate.format() }`, { headers: headers })
.then((response) => {
    return {priceEvents: response.data}
})
.then(({priceEvents}) => {
    return axios.get(`/api/v1/test/events?date_from=${ currentDate.format() }`, { headers: headers })
        .then(response => {
            return {priceEvents, bookingEvents: response.data}
        })
})
.then(({priceEvents, bookingEvents}) => {
    const defaultDate = this.cal.$calendar.fullCalendar("getDate");
    this.setState({ priceEvents, bookingEvents, defaultDate });

    console.log(bookingEvents);
    console.log(priceEvents);
});
```

You could also use await. It's a bit cleaner in this situation.

```js
async function doStuff() {
    const {data: priceEvents} = await axios.get(`/api/v1/test/prices?date_from=${ currentDate.format() }`, { headers: headers })
    const {data: bookingEvents} = await axios.get(`/api/v1/test/events?date_from=${ currentDate.format() }`, { headers: headers })

    const defaultDate = this.cal.$calendar.fullCalendar("getDate");
    this.setState({ priceEvents, bookingEvents, defaultDate }); // 'this' may not refer to your react component in this case

    console.log(bookingEvents);
    console.log(priceEvents);
}

doStuff()
```

Also, since the two axios requests don't depend on each other, you could run them in parallel:

```js
Promise.all([
    axios.get(`/api/v1/test/prices?date_from=${ currentDate.format() }`, { headers: headers }),
    axios.get(`/api/v1/test/events?date_from=${ currentDate.format() }`, { headers: headers }),
])
    .then(([priceResponse, eventsResponse]) => {
        return {
            priceEvents: priceResponse.data,
            bookingEvents: eventsResponse.data,
        }
    })
    .then(({priceEvents, bookingEvents}) => {
        const defaultDate = this.cal.$calendar.fullCalendar("getDate");
        this.setState({ priceEvents, bookingEvents, defaultDate });

        console.log(bookingEvents);
        console.log(priceEvents);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks muchly. This worked. And also thanks for pointing out other different ways.